# Facebook - why if i connect album or photo, returning false

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Thursday i could connected with user album and photo. but Friday & today (Monday) i can't..
there is something bug with Graph API??

and how to create album in page (business page) with Graph API?? i got the identifier and i can access with https://graph.facebook.com/121845897865800 but if i check manually in my page, i couldn't find that..

i using permission: publish_stream,offline_access,user_photo_video_tags,manage_pages
need help!!

Comment: oh i see. because i'm new in stackoverflow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first matter, things like to go in and out with the facebook API. It may even be a result of the devs trying to fix the issue with your second point. If it does not fix soon, [fill out a bug report](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/) or search [the forums](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/)

as for the second this is a known bug: 
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=11254
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10607

I suggest adding your email to the bug reports to keep track of facebook's progress with fixing them. Facebook says "it is being actively worked on." whick means it could be a while.